# Command 'nvcc' not callable from shell script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, cuda

For my shell script, it is critical to check whether CUDA is installed by running `nvcc --version`. If I try to invoke it, it exits with following error:

```
./cuda.sh: line 17: nvcc: command not found
```

Note that I have CUDA installed and the command `nvcc` works when used in the console. For the `nvcc` command to work, some paths must be defined in the `.bashrc` (which they are), but elsewhere I have read that for non-interactive shell, it also has to be added to `.profile`, which I did. Despite this, the script still does not find the command.

What did I wrong and how can I fix this? Did I forget something?

*Thanks for your help!*

Comment: See [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) for what files are executed when

Comment: Also [Bash Startup Files (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) might be clearer

Comment: I checked those two and cannot quite figure out what to do, can you perhaps help me out with this, please? I discovered that BASH_ENV holds the files that are loaded when a non-interactive shell is being started. But that variable is empty and when I try to change it before calling the script, it still doesn't work. What do I have to do to permit a shell script loading .bashrc at startup?

Comment: if your script isn't meant to be shared or portable, you can call `nvcc` with full path in it. (the path can be found with `command -v nvcc` in your interactive shell)